# how to calculate this line integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi} (16\sin^2 3t +16\cos^2 4t)\sqrt{(144\cos^2 3t +256\sin^2 4t)}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I am working on a line integral to calculate the amount of chocolate to cover a pretzel.
the density of the pretzel is given by this formula $\lambda=3(x^2+y^2)$
and the parameter equation of a pretzel shape is given by

$$x(t)=-4\sin 3t \quad\text{and}\quad y(t)=4\cos4t$$

apply the mass formula $\int_C \rho (x,y)\,ds$

I get

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left((16\sin^2 3t +16\cos^2 4t)\sqrt{144\cos^2 3t +256\sin^2 4t}\right) \,dt$$

then I have no idea how calculate this line integral.

can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's not $4\cos 3t$ or $-4\sin 4t$?

Comment: @Dylan I am sure everything above are right. It is -4cos3t and 4cos4t.

Comment: This integral does not have an elementary solution. The best you can do is try numerical methods

Comment: Are those limits right? Graphing from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives a somewhat strange result. The path drawn as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}2$, which starts at the single hump and ends at the rightmost twist, is the reverse of the path from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\pi$. Then from there the path continues to the rightmost of the double hump, stops at the tip when $t=\frac{15\pi}{12}$, then jumps to the end of the new twist at $t=\frac{16\pi}{12}$, and connects to the rightmost hump at $t=\frac{19\pi}{12}$, "completing" the loop. Sorry for the poor descriptions, I'm not so good with pretzel geometry...

Comment: I only ask because this path seems strange to me; I would think the chocolate should start at one twist-end, travel over the loops, and end at the other twist-end in a continuous fashion.

Comment: @user170231 the path looks strange to me, too. but it comes with the problem.